# card.io: Camera support only available on armv7(s) architecture -- can't use camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, arm

i don't know about  armv7(s) architecture in ios. i am creating an application that have to use paypal. actually i don't know why this type of warning occured while presenting PayPalPaymentViewController.

Please suggest me.

Comment: are you running it in the simulator? because the simulator is not arm

Comment: yes currently in simulator. but why this warning occur.

Comment: i guess the library you are using needs the camera, and it may be using some precompiled code that is for arm architecture only

Comment: then it may be possible when i run in actual device. this warning will not come ?

Comment: yes most likely wont

Comment: Did you fixed this issue? I am facing same issue.